# Undefined variable: _SESSION

Tags: php, html

não estou conseguindo resolver esse problema :/,

**Arquivo formulario.php:**

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<form action="x.php" method="post">

  <?php  
      $_SESSION["urlName"] = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];

      echo $_SESSION["urlName"]; // o valor é exibido aqui no formulario.php.
  ?>

    <input type="email">
    <button type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

**Arquivo x.php:**

```
<?php
    require("redirect.php");

    $urlName = $_SESSION["urlName"]; //o valor não chega aqui no x.php, Pq?

    if(isset($_SESSION["urlName"]))
        echo $urlName;
    else
        echo "URL NÃO encontrada";

pageRedirect($urlName);
```

**Arquivo redirect.php:**

```
function pageRedirect($urlName){
    header("Location: " . $urlName);
    die();
}
```

Resumindo o código:

Eu abro a `$_SESSION` no arquivo **formulario.php**, quando o usuário da o **submit**, ele armazena a url em uma `$_SESSION` e redireciona o usuário para o arquivo **x.php**, lá no arquivo **x.php** eu tento exibir a `$_SESSION` armazenada, porém, sem sucesso.

**Mensagem de erro:** *Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION*

**Caso eu coloque session_start(); no arquivo x.php também, a mensagem de erro muda:**

```
Esta página não está funcionando
MEUIP enviou uma resposta inválida.
ERR_INVALID_REDIRECT
```

Comment: session_start() está em x.php também?

Comment: não, quando eu coloco aparece essa mensagem: `enviou uma resposta inválida.
ERR_INVALID_REDIRECT`

Comment: Seu arquivo formulário.php está errado, não tem tags de abertura nem de fechamento php e está misturado com html reveja sua sintaxe

Comment: @MagicHat foi só um exemplo está com as tags corretas `<?php  session_start(); ?>`

Comment: Assim, se vc quer ajuda coloque com a sintaxe correta, ainda continua errado.

Comment: você possui um trecho de php dentro do form html que não possui as tags php, reveja sua sintaxe...

Comment: @MagicHat já editei, no código está com as tags.

Comment: No topo da página `x` dê um `var_dump($_SESSION)` e cola o resultado

Comment: Resultado é `NULL`, sem o `<?php session_start(); ?>` na página `x`, com o `<?php session_start(); ?>` na página `x` não aparece nada, apenas `Esta página não está funcionando
MEUIP enviou uma resposta inválida.
ERR_INVALID_REDIRECT`

Comment: Tem algum redirecionamento de htaccess?

Comment: @MagicHat eu removi uma função que faz o redirect e consegui receber o valor, porém é justamente isso que quero fazer, pegar a url e colocar essa url no header

Comment: Edite sua questão colocando exatamente o código que tens e detalhando passo a passo o que deseja fazer.

Comment: @MagicHat Editei

Answer (score 1):

Como você quer acessar a variável de sessão, você também precisa iniciar a sessão de ambos os arquivos:

```
session_start();

$urlName = $_SESSION["urlName"]; //o valor não chega aqui no x.php, Pq?

if(isset($_SESSION["urlName"]))
    echo $urlName;
else
    echo "URL NÃO encontrada";
```

Comment: Quando eu coloco `session_start();` no x.php aparece essa mensagem: `enviou uma resposta inválida.
ERR_INVALID_REDIRECT`

Comment: O erro indica que o redirecionamento é inválido/inexistente. Verifique qual o caminho que a variável de sessão 'urlName' está recebendo e se faz sentido no seu projeto. Outra coisa, se você estiver utilizando um servidor (exemplo Apache), verifique se você deu as permissões necessárias de acesso para aquele arquivo.

Comment: estou verificando aqui, fazendo alguns testes, pelomenos agora eu já tenho um "norte"

Comment: Pelo que vi na outra discussão você quer fazer algo do tipo: **header('Location: '.$_SESSION['urlName']);** certo? Verifique o valor de urlName.

Comment: exato, eu complementei o código no tópico, agora estou verificando o tipo do valor que recebo no urlName

Comment: já verifiquei o tipo e o valor estão corretos, o valor é a url desejáda, e o tipo dela é string, o que estou fazendo de errado? :s

Comment: Quando você verifica em **echo $_SESSION["urlName"];** o caminho desejado é o correto então? Porém ele acusa erro de redirecionamento, uma das possibilidades é de ele não "enxergar" o **path/para/o/meu/arquivo.php** por causa de permissão na pasta (como 755 no Apache). Ou o caminho está fora do escopo. Como a sua pergunta foi uma e a resposta foi dada, e agora surgiu outro problema, sugiro criar uma nova pergunta com o problema sugerido.

Comment: o caminho está correto, tanto é que se eu copiar o resultado da `$_SESSION["urlName"];` ,e colar na barra do navegador e der enter, ele vai para o local especificado na session, como eu resolvo esse negócio de permissao 755 do apache?

Comment: Sobre o Apache eu só citei um exemplo, porque não ficou claro se você estava usando algum servidor. Se estiver construindo a sua aplicação dentro da pasta **var/www* do Apache, você precisa pesquisar sobre **permissões de acesso** com os comandos **chmod, chown** (leitura, escrita etc) dos seus arquivos e pastas, e qual a melhor maneira para o seu projeto e como fazer essas alterações de acordo com o seu sistema operacional. Mas o problema parece não ser esse e eu não consigo enxergar como te ajudar.

Comment: Tudo bem, obrigado mesmo assim, você e os outros ajudaram bastante, vou criar outro tópico com o novo problema, e sim estou usando apache xampp/htdocs/nomeProjeto/index.php

Answer (score -1):

Primeiro você faz um teste simples. Crie dois arquivos, por exemplo, `a.php` e `b.php`, no primeiro inicialize alguma variavel de sessão, no segundo tente acessa-la.

`a.php`

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['teste'] = 'Funcionou';
echo $_SESSION['teste'];
?>
```

`b.php`

```
<?php
session_start();

echo $_SESSION['teste'];
?>
```

Acesse primeiro o a.php e depois acesse o b.php, e veja se funciona.

Comment: Obrigado pela sua ajuda, a discussão agora é, porque eu recebo o valor `$urlName = "www.google.com.br"`; em minha session o tipo do valor é string, e quando eu passo para essa função, `function pageRedirect($urlName){
    header("Location: " . $urlName);
    die();
}` da essa mensagem de erro : `Esta página não está funcionando
192.168.0.70 enviou uma resposta inválida.
ERR_INVALID_REDIRECT` **OBS:** a url do google foi só um exemplo.