# Problema com redirecionamento PHP+Apache XAMPP

Tags: php, html, apache

O problema é o seguinte:

**Arquivo formulario.php:**

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<form action="x.php" method="post">

  <?php  
      $_SESSION["urlName"] = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];

      echo $_SESSION["urlName"];
  ?>

    <input type="email">
    <button type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

**Arquivo x.php:**

```
<?php
    require("redirect.php");

    $urlName = $_SESSION["urlName"];

    if(isset($_SESSION["urlName"]))
        echo $urlName;
    else
        echo "URL NÃO encontrada";

pageRedirect($urlName);
```

**Arquivo redirect.php:**

```
<?php
    function pageRedirect($urlName){
        header("Location: " . $urlName);
        die();
    }
```

**Valor recebido no** `$urlName`:

> "192.168.x.xx:xxx/projeto/site-x/index.php"

**Tipo:** String

**MENSAGEM DE ERRO:**

> Esta página não está funcionando
>   192.168.x.xx enviou uma resposta inválida. ERR_INVALID_REDIRECT

*

**OBS:** Não é duplicata de **[Undefined variable: _SESSION](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/267899/undefined-variable-session)**, são questões diferentes.

**Arquivo hosts:**

```
# copyright (c) 1993-2009 microsoft corp.
#
# this is a sample hosts file used by microsoft tcp/ip for windows.
#
# this file contains the mappings of ip addresses to host names. each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. the ip address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# the ip address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# for example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within dns itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
```

Comment: @Fernando aquele post era sobre o assunto da session, esse é sobre o erro de redirecionamento, o pessoal do outro post que me aconselhou a criar um novo tópico com esse novo problema

Comment: Você tem acesso aos arquivos do apache, qual o seu sistema operacional?

Comment: @MagicHat SO: Windows, creio que sim.

Comment: Como está `C:/WINDOWS/system32/drivers/etc/hosts`?

Comment: @MagicHat editei o tópico, coloquei o conteúdo de hosts nele.

Comment: Descomente a linha do `localhost`.

Comment: `127.0.0.1       localhost` e reinicie o apache.

Comment: @MagicHat resolvi algumas coisas, agora o problema é outro :s, ele redireciona, porem ele não apaga a url que estava antes, ele só complementa ela. exemplo: ele vai até a url: `localhost/projetos/site/x.php`, e quando executa a função, fica assim a url  `localhost/projetos/site/x.php/localhost/index.php`, e o objetivo é apenas redirecionar para `localhost/index.php`

Comment: @MagicHat ARRUMEEEEEEEEI Finalmente kkkkk, nossa, como é ruim não saber fazer as coisas kkkk, obrigado pela ajuda Magic, não era problema no apache não, foram 2 erros, 1 foi que não tinha session_start no formulario.php(sim eu tinha colocado, devo ter apagado pra fazer test e acabei não voltando ele), e o outro erro dps de ter arrumado esse, era que no `header("Location: " . $urlName);`, tinha que colocar o `http://` `header("Location: http://" . $urlName);`

Answer (score 1):

Esse problema ocorre porque a função `echo` altera o header da resposta e então você não consegue mais usar a função `header()`. Nesse o ideal seria não usar a função `echo` para conseguir usar a função `header()` normalmente.

Comment: retirei o echo, e o http:// e o erro continuou :s.

Comment: ainda precisa do `http://...` porque você está redirecionando para uma url, se redirecionar apenas para um arquivo (sem o `192.168.x.xx:xxx/ ..`) não seria necessário.

Comment: Como eu faço isso?

Comment: Você pode passar apenas o caminho relativo do arquivo como você faz quando usa o require.

Comment: aaa sei, vou ver aqui se modifico e dou um feedback ^^

Comment: Já pensou em implementar sua função para verificar se a url tem o http/https e adicionar automaticamente, caso não tenha? Dá pra fazer ligeiro com expressões regulares. Kd o feedback?